# Java - Deleting files and folder of parent path recursively

Tags: java, file

I'm creating a java program which takes parent path and deletes all the files and folders in the given path. I'm able to delete files and folder's files inside another folder in the parent folder but not able to delete folders at 3rd level.

Here's my code:

```
package com.sid.trial;

import java.util.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DeleteFilesOfDirectoryWithFilters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String parentPath = "D:\\tester";
        List<String> folderPaths =  deleteFiles(parentPath);
        deleteFolders(folderPaths);
    }

    public static void deleteFolders(List<String> folderPaths) {

        for(String path : folderPaths){
            File folder = new File(path);
            if(folder.delete())
                System.out.println("Folder "+folder.getName()+" Successfully Deleted.");
        }
    }

    public static List<String> deleteFiles(String path){
        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] files = folder.listFiles();
        List<String> folderPaths = new ArrayList<String>();
        String folderPath = path;
        if(files.length == 0){
            System.out.println("Directory is Empty or No FIles Available to Delete.");
        }
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile() && file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
                System.out.println("File "+file.getName()+" Successfully Deleted.");
            } else {
                if(file.isDirectory()){
                    folderPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    char lastCharacter = path.charAt(path.length()-1);
                    if(!(lastCharacter == '/' || lastCharacter == '\\')){

                        folderPath = folderPath.concat("\\");
                    }
                    /*folderPath = folderPath.concat(file.getName());*/
                    System.out.println(folderPath);
                    folderPaths.add(folderPath);
                }
            }
        }
        for(String directoryPath : folderPaths){
            List<String> processedFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
            processedFiles = deleteFiles(directoryPath);
            folderPaths.addAll(processedFiles);
        }
        return folderPaths;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this an excercise? Otherwise you could look at commons-io - FileUtils.cleanDirectory: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#line.1666

Comment: @Siddharth Take a look at my solution below.

Comment: Please do not request for readers to do the whole thing for you - Stack Overflow is not a free coding service. The point is that people are willing to help you achieve your goal, so be willing to take people's ideas and suggestions, and modify them to your use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the ""new"" Java File API with Stream API:

```
 Path dirPath = Paths.get( "./yourDirectory" );
 Files.walk( dirPath )
      .map( Path::toFile )
      .sorted( Comparator.comparing( File::isDirectory ) ) 
      .forEach( File::delete );
```

Note that the call to `sorted()` method is here to delete all files before directories.

About one statement, and without any third party library ;)

Comment: This code is really new thanks for sharing :).  Can you please explain it a bit? And let me now how can I print all file and folder names as well like I'm doing it in my code using File API with Stream API.?

Comment: `Files.walk()` returns a Stream of all existing paths into the directory. `map()` transforms Path objects into File objects, and `forEach()` applies something to each of them.

To print file paths during processing you can expand the lambda into `forEach()` and just add a statement: 
`forEach( file -> {  System.out.println( file ); file.delete(); } );`

Answer (score 6):

You should consider using [Apache Commons-IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/). It has a FileUtils class with a method deleteDirectory that will recursively delete.

**Note:** Apache Commons-IO (as for version 2.5) provides utilities only for legacy `java.io` API (`File` and friends), not for Java 7+ `java.nio` API (`Path` and friends).

Comment: This will delete parent folder too. The question is how to keep the parent folder but remove all files inside.

Answer (score 3):

You can recursively traverse through the folder and delete each file one by one. After deleting all the files in one folder, delete the folder. Something similar to following code should work:

```
public void delete(File path){
    File[] l = path.listFiles();
    for (File f : l){
        if (f.isDirectory())
            delete(f);
        else
            f.delete();
    }
    path.delete(); 
}
```

Comment: gives java.lang.StackOverFlowError on windows 10 machine. Any clue/improvments in code above?

Comment: this code works fine in Java 1.8 & Windows 8.1 . Thanks @santosh-patil

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, your recursion is longer than needed.

```
public static void deleteFiles (File file){    
    if(file.isDirectory()){
        File[] files = file.listFiles();   //All files and sub folders
        for(int x=0; files != null && x<files.length; x++)
            deleteFiles(files[x]);          
    }
    else
        file.delete();      
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. When invoke `deleteFiles()` on a ***file***, the else statement gets triggered, the single file will be deleted with no recursion.
2. When invoke `deleteFiles()` on a ***folder***, the if-statement gets triggered.

   - Get all the entries (files of folders residing in the folder) as an array
   - If there exist sub-entries, for each entry, ***recursively*** delete the sub-entry (the same process (1 and 2) repeats).

---

*Be careful when implementing deletion of file and folders. You may want to print out all the files and folders name first instead of deleting them. Once confirmed it is working correctly, then use `file.delete()`.*

Comment: The problem with this code is that it also deletes the parent file.

Comment: @Siddharth What do you mean by parent file. You mean the folder?